# flask-jwt-extended gives same token all the time for /login requests

Tags: python-2.7, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

jwt-flask-extended sends back same access token for any user always. I have integrated Flask with apache. Using Python 2.7.5, Operating System - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo). Find the code below.

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)

    @app.before_request
    def log_request_info():
            app.logger.debug('Headers: %s', request.headers)
            app.logger.debug('Body: %s', request.get_data())

    mysql = MySQL()

    # MySQL configurations
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'userdb'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'mysql-host'

    mysql.init_app(app)

    # Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
    app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'Changeit'  # Change this! if needed
    app.config['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = timedelta(seconds=28800)
    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    @app.route('/auth/token', methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        if not request.is_json:
           return jsonify({"msg": "Missing JSON in request"}), 400

        uid = request.json.get('uid', None)
        username = request.json.get('username', None)

        if not uid:
            return jsonify({"msg": "Missing required parameter"}), 400
        if not username:
            return jsonify({"msg": "Missing required parameter"}), 400

        # Identity can be any data that is json serializable
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=uid)
        return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSGIPassAuthorization On.

I added this directive to Apache mod wsgi config file. It started working as expected .

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using global variables which aren't thread safe.

Your access token variable should go inside a function or a method.

If you still want it globally accessible, you can use Werkzeug's `local` package along with Flask's `g` variable.

I recommend putting it in a method though.

Comment: The token generation is inside @app.route('/auth/token', methods=['POST'])
    def login():. Not using the global variables..

Comment: Well this module looks fine now. Do you have other modules? What change caused the break? How are you testing your code?